# Shopify Webhooks and Graphql

Tags: graphql, webhooks, shopify-app, shopify-api, shopify-api-node

I have 2 sets of questions. 1 is regarding the webhooks and the other is graphql

I created a webhook but it is getting removed after a few days and upon doing research for a week, It needs to be verified, and i can confirmed that it is verified, it's just that it is receiving duplicate webhook id. I am not sure what else to do.
[image: Here's the error log.]

Here's my code

```
define(
    "CLIENT_SECRET",
    "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
);
function verify_webhook($data, $hmac_header)
{
    $calculated_hmac = base64_encode(
        hash_hmac("sha256", $data, CLIENT_SECRET, true)
    );
    return hash_equals($calculated_hmac, $hmac_header);
}

$hmac_header = $_SERVER["HTTP_X_SHOPIFY_HMAC_SHA256"];

$data = file_get_contents("php://input");
$verified = verify_webhook($data, $hmac_header);

if ($verified) {
    http_response_code(200);
    error_log("X_SHOPIFY_WEBHOOK_ID: " . $_SERVER["HTTP_X_SHOPIFY_WEBHOOK_ID"]);
    error_log("-----");
}
```

This code is working fine, but after a couple of days it gets removed. Any idea?

The other thing is just want to clarify something. It is currently working but i believe that it is not right at some point.

So the reason i am using that webhook is when PRODUCT is created or updated, we want to add data into the variants, currently what i am doing is getting the number of variants of the product based on the payload of the webhook, then using a for loop for the GRAPHQL to add the metafields.

Here's the code for that.

```
foreach ($variants as $key => $variant) {
        $id = $variant["node"]["id"];
        $createdAt = $variant["node"]["createdAt"];

        $query2 = 'mutation($input: ProductVariantInput!) {
                productVariantUpdate(input: $input) {
                  productVariant {
                    metafield(namespace:"variant", key: "date_created") {
                      value
                    }
                  }
                }
              }';
        $variables2 = [
            "input" => [
                "id" => $id,
                "metafields" => [
                    "namespace" => "variant",
                    "key" => "variant_date_created",
                    "value" => json_encode($createdAt),
                    "valueType" => "STRING",
                ],
            ],
        ];
        $payload2 = [
            "query" => $query2,
            "variables" => $variables2,
        ];
        $response2 = $client->request("POST", $GLOBALS["GRAPHQL"], [
            "json" => $payload2,
        ]);
        $body2 = $response2->getBody()->getContents();
        print_r($body2);
    }
```

Again, as i said this graphql is working fine, but i know there's a much better way to do it rather than looping.

Thanks